# What does Oracle return for select?

Tags: oracle, select

When a select statement is executed against an Oracle database, what does the db return? Is it a cursor reference or something else?

Comment: I am guessing the question is about the underlying return data stream, in SQL Server it returns TDS for example.

Comment: @Sathya, just like any other selects. For example, select * from emp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide the full answer, only the starting point.

SQL*Net is sitting on top of TNS (Transparent Network Substrate) and is how your connection is established and then used to send commands and results between the client and server. You will need to dig into the SQL*Net architectural documentation to try find an answer. It is unlikely to be a 'simple' format, and I would expect it to be propriatary and subject to additional licenses to get to the underlying specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Andrew. I'm only looking for an answer as simple as what are result sets in development frameworks represented as on the database. For example, when you are iterating over a result set, are you essentially looping through a cursor on the db? The answer will help me with resource management on the server. Looks like I have lots of homework to do. :)

Comment: Start digging into the SQL*Net documentation on Oracle's site.